# Why does `make-symbol` work in macro expansion, just as `gensym` works?

Tags: elisp, symbols, macroexpansion

In the dash library I noticed the use of `make-symbol` to avoid symbol conflicts during macro expansion.

```lisp
(defmacro --filter (form list)
  "Anaphoric form of `-filter'.
See also: `--remove'."
  (declare (debug (form form)))
  (let ((r (make-symbol "result")))
    `(let (,r)
       (--each ,list (when ,form (!cons it ,r)))
       (nreverse ,r))))
```

From what I read in common lisp books, `gensym` is used for things like this to create a unique symbols via.

```
(let ((r (cl-gensym "result"))) ...)
```

I'm confused because when I macro expand this kind of form.

```
(let ((result '(1 2 3 4)))
  (--filter (> 2 it) result))
```

I get this and it looks like the symbol created with `make-symbol` named `result` is indeed conflicting with the `result` that contains `'(1 2 3 4)`.

In fact, when I copy the result of this macroexpansion and run it myself I get what I expect: nil.

```
(let ((result '(1 2 3 4)))
  (let
      (result)
    (--each result
      (when
          (> 2 it)
        (!cons it result)))
    (nreverse result)))
```

But this seems to work. Instead of returning nil as I would expect from the macroexpansion. Why is this?

```
(let ((result '(1 2 3 4)))
  (--filter (> 2 it) result))
;; => (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the same symbol, even though it has the same name.  This returns `(nil foo)`, because the interned symbol `foo` created by reading `'foo` is *not the same symbol* as the uninterned symbol `foo` returned by `make-symbol`.

```lisp
(let ((res  (make-symbol "foo"))) (list (eq res 'foo) res))
```

`C-h f make-symbol` says:

> `make-symbol` is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(make-symbol NAME)`
>
> Return a newly allocated **uninterned** symbol whose name is `NAME`.
>
> Its value is void, and its function definition and property list are `nil`.
>   This function does not change global state, including the match data.

`cl-gensym` also creates an uninterned symbol.  As the [Common Lisp doc for `gensym`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gensym.htm) says:

> Creates and returns a *fresh*, *uninterned* *symbol*, as if by calling `make-symbol`. 
>   (The only difference between `gensym` and `make-symbol` is in how the *new-symbol*'s *name* is determined.)
>
> The *name* of the *new-symbol* is the concatenation of a prefix, which defaults to `"G"`, and a suffix, which is the decimal representation of a number that defaults to the *value* of `*gensym-counter*`.

Unfortunately, the Elisp doc for `gensym` does not include the helpful info about its similarity and difference from `make-symbol`.  The Common Lisp doc is better, in this case.

---

As for your related question in the comments: "Why would anyone use `gensym`, since the names are not meaningful?":

- You can programmatically produce the symbol names with `gensym`. If you just need a few such symbols (e.g. hand-coding) then you can of course use `make-symbol`, to have meaningful names.
- Sometimes you don't care what the names are, or there may be a lot of them - again, especially when the code is generated by program.

The second case is akin to using `x1`, `x2`,... and `y1`, `y2`,... versus using `x`, `y`, `z`,...  (But the numerals need to be unique across the Emacs session.) Another analogy would be GUIDs.

`gensym` does let you provide a *name prefix*, and that can be meaningful, e.g., for a group of symbols having something in common.

Comment: Why would we ever use `gensym` over `make-symbol` for macros then?  `make-symbol` makes the macro expansion easier to read since it doesn't append numbers to a symbol.

Comment: Maybe this is a separate question. Lmk if I should ask separately.

Comment: (1) You can programmatically produce the symbol names with `gensym`. If you just need a few (hand coding) then you can of course use `make-symbol`, to have meaningful names. (2) Sometimes you don't care what the names are - again, especially when the code is created by program.